# TypeScript Error: JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag in StencilJS

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, jsx, stenciljs

I'm working on a StencilJS component, and I've run into a TypeScript error which states:

`TypeScript ./src/components/main/e-menu/e-menu.tsx, line 45, column 10 JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.`

The line in question is:

```
<div class="container gl-column">
```

Here's the general structure surrounding the line:

```
<Host>
  <div class="container gl-column"> 
    <!-- Other nested elements and components -->
  </div>
  <e-footer
    showInternetStatus={true}
    onClickHelp={() => this.help.emit()}
  ></e-footer>
</Host>
```

I've ensured that every opening  has a corresponding closing  tag, but the error still persists.

The code in between the closing tags has also nothing to do with the problem, because I've tested it without it and it still resulted in the same error.

I'm unsure why this error is appearing. Is this a known issue with TypeScript and StencilJS, or might there be something subtle I'm overlooking? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strange. Have you tried building just `<Host><div></div></Host>`?  I've occasionally had strange issues that were resolved only by deleting components.d.ts or a fresh npm install or even a fresh clone of the repo.